# Duplicate TableView in CollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have horizontal CollectionView with TableView on each

### Problem

Table view duplicates

### Code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OrdersCollectionViewCell.id, for: indexPath) as! OrdersCollectionViewCell

        switch indexPath.row{
        case 0:
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
            cell.setupTableview()
            cell.tableView.backgroundColor = .red
        case 1:
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
        case 2:
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        case 3:
            cell.backgroundColor = .orange
        case 4:
            cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
        default:
            break
        }
        return cell
    }
```

`setupTableview()` -> just delegate and dataSource

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You will have to reload you table view in `cellForItemAt ` method as it reuses the cell. Also call remove table method for rest of the cells as you're setting up table for first cell only.

Comment: What is `setupTableView()`? Add code of this method to your question

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OrdersCollectionViewCell.id, for: indexPath) as! OrdersCollectionViewCell

    switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        cell.setupTableview()
        cell.tableView.backgroundColor = .red
    case 1:
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
    case 2:
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    case 3:
        cell.backgroundColor = .orange
    case 4:
        cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    default:
        break
    }
    cell.tableView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

It may helps you. Thank you.